# aggregation involves dependency?

Tags: oop, uml

I'm doing an UML diagrams for a project but I have a doubt...
I use an example to explain:

```
public class Book{...}

public class Library{
    private ArrayList<Book> books;

    public void insert(Book b){...}

    public Book get(Book b){...}
    }
```

In this case between Book and Library there's an aggregation but also a dependency, right?
Aggregation is a relation in which the "parent" class contains the "child" class, instead the dependency is the case in which a class use another class by parameter or return type.
Now, if a class A contains object of another class B mean that the B's object has been passed in some way at the object of class A, the only way is using a method(or a constructor), so the aggregation involves the dependency?

P.S.: sorry for my poor english

Comment: Now during an email exchange with my Professor he said me that in this case there isn't an aggregation but only a dependency because the class Library contains a structure(ArrayList in this case) of object of Book...

So if contains directly an object is a aggregation, otherwise is a dependency???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no UML expert, but one thing I've really liked in ["UML in a Nutshell"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/UML-2-0-Nutshell-Desktop-Reference/dp/0596007957) was a sentence saying that UML is useful only when it's intuitive for everybody.

Having said that, I'd suggest not over-complicating your diagrams. Not everything can nor has to be presented in a diagram. In your case the `Library` has some `Books`, a case of aggregation/composition (depending on other details not mentioned in your description). You dont have to state a dependency between these two classes, because the aggregation implies it. In my understanding a "dependency" is useful when you want to state an indirect relationship, a runtime dependency for instance.

Comment: Also the answer of vainolo is very good, but i choose your answer as the "accepted answer" because you have been the first

Answer (score 4):

With all due respect to your professor, I disagree. You do have aggregation in your diagram, since `Library` contains `Books` (both semantically and syntactically).

A UML dependency relation means that "some UML element or a set of elements requires, needs or depends on other model elements for specification or implementation" (from my favorite UML reference site: [uml-diagrams.org](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/dependency.html?cid=26)). When you put an aggregation link between two elements, it is already stated that one depends on the other, therefore adding a dependency relation between them is redundant.